# Create multi-layered json in bash

Tags: json, bash

I have a script that puts AWS access keys into secrets manager in AWS.

This is a key rotation script. So the script may encounter either one or two keys that need to be rotated, depending on the user.

The script produces valid json if it prints out only one key:

```
printf '{"Access Key1":"%s","Secret Key1":"%s"}\n' "$new_access_key1" "$new_secret_key1" > "$ofile"
```

However, the JSON breaks if you print the second key. If that happens what you end up with is this non-working JSON:

```
{"Access Key1":"AKIAI7TJSSQMHSAD5UWQ","Secret Key1":"secret-key-contents"}
{"Access Key2":"AKIAJ3ZSNMIVGMVHYEQQ","Secret Key2":"secret-key-contents"}
```

I want the resulting json to look like this if there's one key:

```
{
    "Access Keys": {
        "Access Keys 1": {
            "Access Key1": "AKIAI4I2T3ZASJN762KQ",
            "Secret Key1": "secret-key-contents"
        }
    }
}
```

Or this if it has to print out two keys:

```
{
    "Access Keys": {
        "Access Keys 1": {
            "Access Key1": "AKIAI4I2T3ZASJN762KQ",
            "Secret Key1": "secret-key-contents"
        },
        "Access Keys 2": {
            "Access Key2": "AKIAI6BAYZQEBA6TTKCQ",
            "Secret Key2": "secret-key-contents"
        }
    }
}
```

I'm using a variable to store the directory I'm printing out to:

```
output_dir="../output_files/aws_secrets"
```

And I'm putting the json into a file that I define with this variable:

```
ofile="$output_dir"/aws-"$aws_user_name"-"$aws_account"-access-keys.json
```

I'm creating or updating the aws secret with this function:

```
store_secret() {
  secret_exists=$(aws secretsmanager list-secrets --max-results 100  --profile company-nonprod  | jq -r '.SecretList[].Name' | grep aws-"$aws_user_name"-"$aws_account"-keys)
  if [[ -z  "$secret_exists" ]]; then
    printf "Creating New AWS Secret:\\n"
    aws secretsmanager create-secret --name aws-"$aws_user_name"-"$aws_account"-keys --description "$aws_user_name's $aws_account Access Keys" --secret-string file://"$ofile" --profile company-nonprod
  else
    printf "Updating AWS Secret:\\n"
    aws secretsmanager update-secret --secret-id aws-"$aws_user_name"-"$aws_account"-keys --secret-string file://"$ofile" --profile company-nonprod
  fi
}
```

I create the AWS keys with this command that uses jq:

```
  readarray  -t new_keys < <(aws iam create-access-key --user-name "$aws_user_name" --profile "$aws_account" |  jq -r '.AccessKey | (.AccessKeyId, .SecretAccessKey)')
  new_access_key1="${new_keys[0]}"
  new_secret_key1="${new_keys[1]}"
```

How can I use print statements to output correctly formatted JSON to the file if the script encounters:

- One key that needs to be printed out
- Or two keys that need to be printed out

Comment: You've been here long enough that you should know what to expect (which is to say, a "*don't* use `echo`, use `jq`" answer).

Comment: That said, we can't reasonably write *any* kind of answer without a specification for what kind of variables/files/&c. the input is stored in.

Comment: OK, thanks Charles Duffy. I will update the OP with some more info.

Comment: If there are only two possibilities, you could just use an `if` statement that prints one way or the other.

Comment: Also matters whether the data is in a sufficiently-restricted domain that it's safe to just use string substitution to stuff it into a JSON document. Which characters are allowed in AWS keys?

Comment: Ok, I've updated the OP with what I hope is useful info (and doesn't go past a minimal example).  As far as the text allowed in AWS keys, the access keys are alphanumeric, and the secret keys are alphanumeric with special characters (=,!,*,/ etc). Would you be able to provide an example of string substitution?

Comment: *Which* specific special characters are allowed matters, because that set needs to be lined up against which special characters are allowed without escaping in JSON literal strings to determine whether it's safe to do this without jq or another JSON-aware tool (ie. whether unusual secret keys will cause your code to occasionally break).

Comment: I was incorrect in saying that secret keys can have special characters. Both access and secret keys use alphanumeric characters. Here is an access key and secret key for a test user I deleted. So posting the secret key is not a risk, since the key is gone now: `Access Key: AKIAIVBOT5ZQH2AG4UAQ
Secret Key: VdAIxAiCkLxSInKetbq2KbppUf9ZIkH7vyuJ4oyk`

That's to give you an example of what that looks like.